# How to link columns from multiple mysql databases within the same mysql install

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, triggers, database-trigger

I run multiple gaming websites, each requires a user to have a certain amount of "experience" to be able to function. However, because of a patchwork job done by developers before me, each website has a separate mysql database with a "users" table, where each "user" has a different value of "experience". Additionally, each user table has some extra columns that might not be shared by the other websites.

What I would like to do is to link this integer value ("experience") among all the websites so that if a user spends some experience on site A, their displayed value on site B also decreases. Ideally this would be done with a simple mysql trigger or in some way where I have to do minimal changes to the actual mysql tables and databases, but just have all the values symlinked.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This would be possible, you would need to have procedures cross checking keys. Maybe provide some code you have already tried? Stack Overflow does not write code for people.

Comment: I dont think you can do it with minimal changes.

Comment: My suggestion is create a centralized `user` table where every game can check user experience

Comment: The problem is these are all databases tied to existing laravel instances. So I am not sure if laravel is capable of querying more than one database (e.g. a centralized database for user info)

Comment: Well you have to do something else. Otherwise you cant guarantee the transaction

Comment: By "databases" do you mean "servers" (separate instances of MySQL), or `CREATE DATABASE`?

Comment: from same mysql install = on one server; Multiple databases on one server.  My solution right now is to try and combine everything into one database though.  And then perhaps create a centralized user table like @JuanCarlosOropeza suggested